# C-Sorting days of the week

Tags: c, sorting, days

Ok so I have an array that lists the 5 weekdays in order:

```
char *days[5]={"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"};
```

Now I have some struct arrays and one of the elements are the days of the week and they are not in order, they are in random order like:

```
d[0].day is "Thursday"
d[1].day is "Monday"
d[2].day is "Wednesday"
```

Now inconveniently the days aren't in alpha order :p  so that makes me wonder how I can implement a sort of some kind =/

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @zmbq sort the array of structs in order of days instead of Thursday, Monday, Wednesday I need them in Monday, Wednesday, Thursday.

Comment: If possible, change the code form using a `char`-array as index to use some integer type. It'll be a hell lot faster. See *Lidong Guo*'s answer (with merged in the comment by *H2CO3*) below as possible approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to make the days of week by enum . Like:

```
enum Days{
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday
}
```

Then you get the day data by  function like

```
void  printDays(enum d,char * buffer)
{
 const char *daysName[] = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"};
 memcpy(buffer,daysName[d-1]);
}
```

Then when you  use

```
 d[0].day is "Thursday"
d[1].day is "Monday"
d[2].day is "Wednesday"
```

It is easy sort .It in fact just store 1,2,3,4,5!

Comment: That enormous `switch` should really be replaced by a `const char *[]`. That's data, not code.

Comment: You might like to added to apporach proposed by *H2CO3* to your answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 I understand your comment, your words really make sense. But how can I store the enum as `const char *` ?  Can you post you answer and show me the trick ?

Comment: @LidongGuo You can't "store an enum as `const char *`". What you do is: `const char *names[] = { "Monday", "Tuesday", ... }` and now you can index the string array using the members of the enum.

Comment: @LidongGuo Okay, no problem, just saying.

Comment: Cool, didn't exactly use enums but the concept was the same, basically what I did was added another element into my structure def which was an integer, monday was 0 and friday was 4, and just sorted based on that integer element.  But I think enums are a more elegant way to do it though :)

Comment: @user2097648 Happy to known my answer is useful .

Answer (score 1):

OK, to sort this properly, you need to be able to compare two structures and see which is earlier. Once you have that, you can use it for sorting with your favorite sorting algorithm.

To convert `s1` and `s2`, you need to convert `s1.day` and `s2.day` into a number - 0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday, etc... and then compare the numbers. Converting a day string to a number is easy - loop over your `days` array, and see which entry in it is identical to `s1.day` .

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that takes a day of the week as parameter and returns an int. Return 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, and so on.

Then write another function that takes two days as parameters, and using the first function, return the earlier day.

Now using these two functions you can implement any standard sorting algorithm. Same as sorting numbers.

Or,

You can have another array of same size as the array containing your structure. You then copy the structure into the new array, but first copy all Sundays, then all Mondays, and so on.